# Min-height 100% inner div

Tags: css, html

I want to have two nested div's:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">A div in a div!!!</div>
</div>
```

Which both should be at least the height of the window. So of course, I set the height of html and body to 100%, such that the outer div can have a `min-height:100%`, and since the height of the html and body elements are known, this is well defined.

However, `min-height` does not say anything about the actual height of the outer div. Hence it is not defined when the inner div is 'calculated'. The inner div may force the outer one to become bigger, or the inner div may be less tall than the outer div.

As far as I googled, I found 2 solutions, which each break in the situations above:

http://jsfiddle.net/5ML3W/

```
.outer {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 500px;
    background: green;
}
.inner {
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    min-height:100%;
    background: red;
}
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bkjHa/1/

```
.outer {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 500px;
    background: green;
}
.inner {
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    min-height:100%;
    background: red;
}
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
```

Essentially the difference is the height property for the outer div.

How can I force my inner div to be at least 100% of the window size and my outer div to stretch if the inner div becomes larger?

In my real world application the outer div is transparent, so I wouldn't really care. However, I am a bit curious, a fix or an explanation that what I want is not possible would be nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually got quite curious about how to solve this "issue". It works the way you want it if you apply `display: table` to the outer div and `display: table-cell` on the inner div.

**1. Fiddle:** Minimum height 100% without any content
**http://jsfiddle.net/5ML3W/1/**

**2. Fiddle:** Both div's expand if content is added to the inner div 
**http://jsfiddle.net/TVY6K/**

And here is the CSS:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.outer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 500px;
    background: green;
    display: table;
    padding: 0 50px;

}
.inner {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 250px;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Haha, I assume tables have the bare requirement that all their cells are included. However, I do wonder if a rendering program needs to have some kind of feedback or even feedback loop to get the cell to the right size and the table to the right size. I mean, the table must be at least the size of the cell and the cell must be 100% of the table. That's a circular dependency, easy for us humans to understand, possibly harder for assembly to simulate.